# Font render vs. Bitmap render in HTML5 canvas?

Tags: html5-canvas, rendering

I'm trying to simulate the scroll pane in HTML canvas.

Maybe font rendering is much slower than bitmap rendering.

I tested it on my phone and PC.

Anyone has a comparison between them?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, font rendering would be slower.

At it's base, html canvas displays pixels so drawing a bitmap is just straightforward copying each bitmap pixel to a canvas pixel (blitting).

Drawing text involves looking up the glyph for each letter, scaling that glyph, positioning that glyph relative to other letters and then finally painting the glyph as pixels on the canvas.  Much more involved than copying bitmap pixels.

Comment: Do you have any code / benchmark that supports your answer?

Comment: I did a benchmark back when I answered. I'll see if I can dig it up for you :-)